# Python Movie group process GSDMM - How to get the list words under each topic?

Tags: python, topic-modeling

Working on Topic modelling on short texts which are comments from customers. Have used the GSDMM - Movie group process to classify the comments under 20 topics.

```
mgp = MovieGroupProcess(K=20, alpha=0.01, beta=0.1, n_iters=30)

vocab = set(x for doc in docs for x in doc)
n_terms = len(vocab)
n_docs = len(docs)

# Fit the model on the data given the chosen seeds
y = mgp.fit(docs, n_terms)
```

I am able to get the topic results next to each comment as "Topic 1",  "Topic 2" .. so on and so forth. How to get the list of top words under each topic? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"Top" Words don´t exist if you use GSDMM, because of how the algorithm works.

Your only option is to get a list with the most common words, which of course will include some words that are frequent in general.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function you can create in python to get the most common words:

```
def generatedfwordfreq(topicnumber, numwords):
    topic = sorted(mgp.cluster_word_distribution[topicnumber].items(), 
key=lambda k: k[1], reverse=True)[:numwords]
    dfm = pd.DataFrame(topic)
    dfm = dfm.rename(columns={0: 'Word', 1: 'Freq'})
    return dfm
```

Above returns a dataframe with Words and Frequencies for top 'numwords' words; numwords being an integer for the number of most common words. Note that mgp stores topic numbers as integers (1,2,3...) so that can be used as 'topicnumber' to reference a particular topic by calling mgp.cluster_word_distribution[topicnumber]